# Is it possible to determine whether or not an improper integral between two assymptotes will converge or not, without having to find its primitive?

Tags: calculus, integration, improper-integrals

I was evaluating $\int_{-1}^{1}\frac{dx}{1-x^2}$ and came to the conclusion it does not converge. I understand it is because its primitive, $F(x)=\frac{1}{2}[\ln(1+x)-\ln(1-x)]$, does not converge at either endpoint. At the same time, $\int_{-1}^{1}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$ converges to $\pi$, which is verified through a simple variable change $x=\cos{u}\Rightarrow\int_{-1}^{1}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}=\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{\sin{u}}{|\sin{u}|}du$.

Is it possible to determine whether or not an improper integral between two assymptotes will converge or not, without having to find its primitive?

Comment: In general, you need to do a comparison test with a known asymptote.  The basic comparisons are $x^{-\alpha}$ for $\alpha>0.$ If it goes to infinity  slower than $x^{-\alpha}$ for  some $0<\alpha<1,$ for example, the improper integral will converge, but if it goes to infinity equal to or faster than $x^{-\alpha}$ for some $\alpha\geq1,$ it won't converge. But in your case, $\alpha=1$ is the appropriate comparison.

Comment: There are borderline asymptotes, like $\frac1{x\log^\beta x}$ which by substitution becomes $\frac1{t^\beta}$ from $-\infty$ and thus converges iff $\beta>1.$ So the $x^{-\alpha}$ comparisons aren't "enough" for all cases, but they often are fine.